# Configuring Omnipay-stripe to work with PCI SCA using Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, pci-compliance, omnipay

I'm following the example on [Stripe Payment Intents](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-stripe) to enable PCI SCA card processing, but receive the following error:

`dev.ERROR: Call to undefined method Omnipay\Stripe\Message\Response::getPaymentIntentReference()`

The code section is copied from the example:

```
$response = $gateway->authorize($purchaseVals)->send();

$paymentIntentReference = $response->getPaymentIntentReference();

$response = $gateway->confirm([
                                'paymentIntentReference' => $paymentIntentReference,
                                'returnUrl' => $completePaymentUrl,
                              ])->send();
```

Does anyone have a clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Versions!

- Laravel Framework 5.8.38
- phpleague/omnipay-stripe 3.1.0

Comment: what versions of all this stuff are you using?

Comment:  Of course! Sorry.